# Web Service exception : An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, console-application

We are working with a third-party company and we are using their webservice. all of the methods work fine except one method whiche requires a byte[] (File) as input.
when we call the method we get this exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://someaddress/Services/DefineMerchant.
> This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
> This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

this is the line that throws the exception:

```
 using (var client = new SomeService.DefineMerchantsClient())
{
   client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "*****";
  client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "****";
   var response = await client.AddRequestDocumentAsync(new MarketerDocEntity { File = requestData.File,   DocumentType = requestData.DocumentType, DocumentTrackingCode = requestData.DocumentTrackingCode });
}
```

and this is my App.config (console application - .Net Framework 4.7.2):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDefineMerchants"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"  />
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
             
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://someaddress/Services/DefineMerchant" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDefineMerchants" contract="SomeService.IDefineMerchants" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDefineMerchants"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="103600"/>
  </system.web>
```

I have also tried this line of code but it didn't work:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Is this exception a server side error(which I don't have access to)? or should I change something in my program?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there may be the following solutions:

1. The firewall. Sometimes this goes wrong because the firewall is turned on, turn it off and try again.
2. Add the following code to the wcf server config.

   `<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />`
3. Check whether the binding `BasicHttpBinding_IDefineMerchants` is defined in the client configuration file. Also if you want to better tracking problem, `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` value can be set to `true`.

Feel free to contact me if have any issues.

Comment: thanks for your response. my firewall is off. I don't have access to server config, it's a third party web service. I have added a reference to this web service in my console app. binding is defined in my client configuration code (As shown above). so you think that it's a server side error and I should contact with that company ?

Comment: You can contact them to see if there are any configuration differences or mismatches.